# Is it possible to have multi password with vault

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I have a deployment project that I share with other teams. I have encrypted my secrets with vault.
I would like to encrypt the production file with a password and a staging file with an other password to avoid other teams having access to production secrets.

Is it possible to do that ?

I have done something like that. My secrets :

```
cat /group_vars/all/vault_production.yml (encrypt with password A)
production_password: 'test1'

cat/group_vars/all/vault_staging.yml (encrypt with password B)
staging_password: 'test2'
```

My environments :

```
cat hosts-production
[all:vars]
env_type=production

cat hosts-staging
[all:vars]
env_type=staging
```

My script :

```
- copy:
  content: |
    env PASS={{hostvars[inventory_hostname][env_type + '_password']}}
  ...
```

And I launch the playbook like that.

```
# for production
ansible-playbook  -i hosts-staging test.yml --vault-password-file .password_a
# for staging
ansible-playbook  -i hosts-staging test.yml --vault-password-file .password_b
```

But that doesn't work because there is 2 differents passwords (ERROR! Decryption failed).
Do you know how to do that ?

Thanks.

BR,

Eric

Comment: My initial feeling is to move the vault files out into someplace they aren't automatically included and explicitly include only the one you need at a time, but I haven't vetted this to see if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, only one vault password allowed per run today. Best way to work around this in the case where you really only need one or the other is to dynamically load a vaulted file based on a var; eg:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
  - secretstuff-{{ env_type }}.yml
  tasks:
  ...
```

or

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - include_vars: secretstuff-{{ env_type }}.yml
  ...
```

depending on if you need the vars to survive for one play or the entire run (the latter will bring them in as facts instead of play vars).

Comment: Thanks Matt. But there is still a problem. With this include, I can't get dynamically the variable : 
For example : 
shell: echo {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][env_type + '_sql_password] }} # is not working
shell: echo {{staging_sql_password}} # is working

Comment: Hrm, that works fine for me on current versions of ansible:
`hostvars[inventory_hostname][env_type + '_sql_password']` when using include_vars. Question is: if you're only loading one or the other, why not just call it "sql_password" and be done with it?

Comment: Whoo, you totally are right @Matt David. It works good like that. Thank you very much. Eric

Answer (score 8):

[Multiple vault passwords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#multiple-vault-passwords) are supported since Ansible 2.4:

```
ansible-playbook --vault-id dev@dev-password --vault-id prod@prompt site.yml
```

> If multiple vault passwords are provided, by default Ansible will attempt to decrypt vault content by trying each vault secret in the order they were provided on the command line.
>
> In the above case, the ‘dev’ password will be tried first, then the ‘prod’ password for cases where Ansible doesn’t know which vault id is used to encrypt something.